# Referencing a cell from another worksheet in a function for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Very novice at VBA so please bear with me.
Im trying to delete a table if a cell (B2) in another sheet changes.

Currently I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B21:D30").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

I've tried many variations, indirect, and different syntax but none work.

Update:
I should also mention that B2 on sheet2 will be changing based on the user selecting a group of radio buttons which are linked to sheet2!B2. I.e. I am not directly changing the value of B2 from sheet2. In fact sheet2 will be eventually hidden.

Comment: You are **never** going to Intersect a private Worksheet_Change's Target with a cell on a different worksheet. Target is the cell or cells **on that worksheet** that have changed so it is impossible to intersect with a cell on another worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is there any other way I can clear my table if a cell from another sheet changes?

Comment: `I should also mention that B2 on sheet2 will be changing based on the user selecting a group of radio buttons which are linked to sheet2!B2.` Write a code to handle the changing of radio buttons and in that do what you want

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes that what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: BTW you can trap changes to a hidden workbook from your current workbook. Posted an answer to demonstrate that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trap the events in the `Sheet2` of the hidden workbook (Let's call it Book2), you need to create a class to manage the `_SheetChange` event capture.

Let's say you want to capture the events in `Book2.Sheet2` from `Book1`. Do this

**1.** Insert a class module (Let's call it `Class1`) and paste this code there

***Code***

```
Private WithEvents hiddenWb As Workbook

Public Property Set Workbook(wb As Workbook)
    Set hiddenWb = wb
End Property

Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
    Set Workbook = hiddenWb
End Property

Private Sub hiddenWb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Range B2 was chnaged"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**2.** In a module paste this code

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim cWb As New Class1

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Set a reference to the hidden workbook
    Set cWb.Workbook = Workbooks("Book2")

    '~~> Change the value of the cell B2
    cWb.Workbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Value = "Blah Blah"
End Sub
```

**Screenshots**

[image]

**Testing**

Run the procedure `Sample()` from `Book1`

**Intresting Read**

[Events And Event Procedures In VBA by Charles H. Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

Comment: Points for referencing chip

Answer (score 0):

This has to be written in the **Sheet2** module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
            .Parent.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B21:D30").ClearContents
        End If
    End with
End Sub
```

Change "Sheet1" to fit your worksheet name.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This works however im actually changing the value of B2 from a radio button on sheet1 (not directly changing B2 from sheet2), And for some reason this does not trigger the ClearContent event. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @user11206088: I think I'll have to see the Option Button Code. It is working fine on my machine. I've added the Option Button and linked cell B2 to it and added Range("B2") = "Change" to the code. And on every click, the range is being deleted.

Comment: The only code I see is:
Public Sub AllowMacros()

    Me.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

However there is a user interface options under format control when you right click the button, that allows you to link to cell.

Could you show me your workbook?

Comment: BTW this will not work if you have a formula in B2. Then you have to use the Worksheet Calculate event. But I guess you would have mentioned if there was a formula in B2. It will work when B2 is changed manually or via VBA.

Comment: I dont believe B2 has a formula. It is just being changed by radio buttons provided by the "form controls" package.

Comment: @user11206088: I have moved the radio button to Sheet1. In its linked cell I've added Sheet2!B2. And the code in the option button I'm using is now Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") = "Change", and it works fine. Why don't you show the code for your option button?

Comment: I pasted the code for the button in my previous comment. But it seems like this is a built in function of the option button and has its own "non-vba" method of populating B2 cell. Can you tell me how your button works, maybe i can copy it as it is working for you